# How to fix unordered scenario & steps execution in Nunit 3 logs and make them ordered

Tags: bdd, specflow, nunit-console

E.g. I have four scenarios in two different features files as below.

```
Feature 1: 

Scenario 1 : Validate title
    Given I am logged in application
    And I verify the title 

Scenario 2: Verify book checkout
    Given I am logged in application
    And I select 2 books 

Feature 2:
    Scenario 1: Verify search books
    Given I am logged in application
    And I search books
```

When the above scenarios are executed in pipeline using Nunit3-console.exe and parallel execution, all scenarios are started at the same time but execution logs are not ordered. See below.

```
Scenario 1: Validate title
Given: I am logged in application
Scenario 2: Verify book checkout
Given I am logged in application and so on..
```

It is clear that Scenario 1 and 2 steps execution logs are not ordered. They are randomly displayed

Comment: After searching for **nunit parallel execution different log files**, I came across this: [Text Output From Tests Spec](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/nunit-internals/specs/Text-Output-from-Tests-Spec.html). This doesn't answer your question, but at least this is something that NUnit acknowledges. That page was about developing a spec for handling output messages during parallel execution.